# Is it possible to use WPF components in asp.net website?

Tags: wpf

I wanted to know if it is possible to use the components from WPF into asp.net web application. Is there any alternate to 3D component like viewport3D(from wpf) in asp.net? I would appreciate if anybody could help.

Answer (score 0):

Your only real bet here is using Silverlight. Having said that, I think what you are trying to achieve is going to require a separate HTML implementation and a lot od duplicated effort.

The short answer is no. WPF is a different presentation framework to HTML and there is no way to translate XAML to HTML with reliable results.